# jQuery - Pegar conteúdo de uma tag <link>

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tenho uma tag link conforme:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="all" href="../css/screen.css" />
```

Ao carregar o site, ela me traz todo o css que esta dentro deste aquivo, mas quando eu vou pegar esse conteúdo com jQuery ele não me retorna nada.

```
console.log( $('link').html() );
(an empty string)
```

Se eu fizer uma chamada somente do seletor o log me retorna o elemento:

```
console.log( $('link') ); // assim eu obtenho o retorno abaixo
Object[link]
```

Minha dúvida é como pegar o conteúdo desse css com o jQuery.

Comment: já tentei $('link').val(), $('link').text() da tudo empty

Comment: Acredito que você tenha que usar AJAX. `.html()` não retorna nada porque não há HTML dentro da tag `link`

Comment: @Lucas se eu usar AJAX eu teria que cair no PHP p/ resolver, queria uma solução jQuery ou no máximo um javascript puro

Comment: Sim, é necessário usar Ajax. Não, não é preciso implementar nada no PHP. Você não implementou nada para que o browser pegue este CSS, porque acha que o Ajax precisaria, sendo que é exatamente a mesma coisa?

Comment: @ViníciusGobboA.deOliveira pode me dar um exemplo

Comment: @SneepSNinjA Não poderia ser mais claro que o Lucas hehehe...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode fazer uma requisição em AJAX usando `$.get`:

```
$.get('../css/screen.css', function(data){
    console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: Oi lucas cheguei nessa solução também, ai o data.responseText me retorna o conteúdo, obrigado!

Answer (score 1):

Você pode experimentar algo assim também, seguindo sua mesma linha de pensamento de obter através da *tag*, sendo `<link>` a única no documento como descrito na sua pergunta:

```
$.ajax({
    url: $('link').prop('href'),
    dataType: "text",
    success: function(cssText) {
        console.log(cssText);
    }
});
```

Naturalmente, para este e outros caso, a `url` deve chamar o mesmo servidor, ou entrar naquela questão de requisições para servidor remoto do *Ajax* (*cross domain*).